# Gulp running different tasks before saving to different output

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to map the result of flattened JavaScript files to two different locations, but I want to do some extra processing on them first. The problem I have is those extra bits are completely different for each.

Here is what I've tried. I want to include a source map when saving the output to `app/scripts`, but I want to not include the source map, but uglify them when saving it to `dist/scripts`.

```
gulp.task('scripts', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/scripts.babel/**/*.js')
    .pipe($.babel({
      presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.sourcemaps.write('.')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts'))
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
})
```

This snippet doesn't do what I want because the result of creating a source map is passed on to the rest of the flow (Besides that, it is actually crashing saying `Unhandled stream error in pipe`). I want to do this using only the same task. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using [`gulp-sourcemaps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) is all wrong. Transformations that should be recorded in source maps must happen between `sourcemaps.init()` and `sourcemaps.write()`. Additionally [`gulp-flatten`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten) does [not support sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support). Luckily for you you can achieve the same with using [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename).

The reason you're getting that error is because you're trying to `uglify()` your source map files. Since those obviously don't contain  valid JS `uglify`'s parser throws up.

The way to solve all this is to simply store your stream in a variable and then `.pipe()` it to two different destinations. However since the underlying [`vinyl` files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl)  are shared between the two resulting streams you need to first clone them using [`gulp-clone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clone) . Otherwise the same files will end up in both destinations.

Finally you use [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) to merge the two resulting streams so you can `return` them from your task.

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('scripts', () => {
  var js = gulp.src('app/scripts.babel/**/*.js')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.babel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))
    .pipe($.rename({dirname:''}))

  return merge(
    js.pipe($.clone())
      .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts')),
    js.pipe($.clone())
      .pipe($.uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts')));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but would "gulp-flatten"-ing the js, then passing it to sourcemaps work? Why do I need to flatten after souremaps.init?

Comment: Because only operations between `sourcemaps.init()` and `sourcemaps.write()` end up in the source maps file. That's just how `gulp-sourcemaps` works.